# Q-values exploding when training DQN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm training a DQN to play OpenAI's Atari environment, but the Q-values of my network quickly explode far above what is realistic.

Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
        if not done:
            # To save on memory, next_state is just one frame
            # So we have to add it to the current state to get the actual input for the network
            next_4_states = np.array(state)
            next_4_states = np.roll(next_4_states, 1, axis=3)
            next_4_states[:, :, :, 0] = next_state
            target = reward + self.gamma * \
                np.amax(self.target_model.predict(next_4_states))
        else:
            target = reward
        target_f = self.target_model.predict(state)
        target_f[0][action] = target

        self.target_model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

The discount factor is 0.99 (it doesn't happen with discount factor 0.9, but also doesn't converge because it can't think far enough ahead).

Stepping through the code, the reason it's happening is all the Q values that aren't meant to be updated (the ones for actions we didn't take) increase slightly. It's my understanding that passing the networks own output to the network during training should keep the output the same, not increase or decrease it. Is there something wrong with my model? Is there some way I can mask the update so it only updates the relevant Q value?

EDIT: My model creation code is here:

```
def create_model(self, input_shape, num_actions, learning_rate):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Convolution2D(32, 8, strides=(4, 4),
                                activation='relu', input_shape=(input_shape)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 4, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(num_actions))

        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate))

        return model
```

I create two of these. One for the online network and one for the target.

Comment: Going to have a crack at implementing a similar architecture in Tensorflow and see if the problem remains.

Comment: I'm confused by how, inside the loop, your model makes predictions with 4 states as input, but outside the loop only takes a single state as input? And what does the index `0` mean in `target_f[0][action] = target`?

Comment: Sorry, my variable naming isn't great. `state` is an array of the four frames leading up to the currents frame (with index 0 being the current frame). To save on memory, `next_state` is just one frame, which is then added to the four frames in `state` (with the last one cut off) to get the input for the network.

The `[0]` is because Keras outputs an array with the shape (1, 9). If I wanted to input more than one state at a time and get multiple outputs, it would give me (2, 9) or (3, 9), etc.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information on what your network architecture looks like (for example code that defines the network)?

Comment: Sure, I'll get the code when I'm at my work PC on Monday. For the network architecture I copied the Atari DQN paper's architecture as closely as I could. 3 convolution layers and a fully connected layer then the output.

Comment: Thank you for this great question! I am trying to understand exploding Q-values better. Could you maybe include your entire code or link to a github page?

Comment: Sorry, @desert_ranger, this was around 4 years ago and I don't have the code any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Which predictions get updated?

> Stepping through the code, the reason it's happening is all the Q values that aren't meant to be updated (the ones for actions we didn't take) increase slightly. It's my understanding that passing the networks own output to the network during training should keep the output the same, not increase or decrease it.

Below I have drawn a very simple neural network with 3 input nodes, 3 hidden nodes, and 3 output nodes. Suppose that you have only set a new target for the first action, and simply use the existing predictions as targets again for the other actions. This results in only a non-zero (for simplicity I'll just assume greater than zero) error (denoted by `delta` in the image) for the first action/output, and errors of `0` for the others.

I have drawn the connections through which this error will be propagated from output to hidden layer in bold. Note how each of the nodes in the hidden layer still gets an error. When these nodes then propagate their errors back to the input layer, they'll do this through **all** of the connections between input and hidden layer, so **all** of those weights can be modified.

So, imagine all those weights got updated, and now imagine doing a new forwards pass with the original inputs. Do you expect output nodes 2 and 3 to have exactly the same outputs as before? No, probably not; the connections from hidden nodes to the last two outputs may still have the same weights, but all three hidden nodes will have different activation levels. So no, the other outputs are not guaranteed to remain the same.

[image: Example Neural Network]

> Is there some way I can mask the update so it only updates the relevant Q value?

Not easily no, if at all. The problem is that the connections between pairs of layers other than the connections between the final pair are not action-specific, and I don't think you want them to be either.

### Target Network

> Is there something wrong with my model?

One thing I'm seeing is that you seem to be updating the same network that is used to generate targets:

```
target_f = self.target_model.predict(state)
```

and

```
self.target_model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

both use `self.target_model`. You should use separate copies of the network for those two lines, and only after longer periods of time copy the updated network's weights into the network used to compute targets. For a bit more on this, see Addition 3 in [this post](https://medium.com/@awjuliani/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-4-deep-q-networks-and-beyond-8438a3e2b8df).

### Double DQN

Apart from that, it is well known that DQN can still have a tendency to overestimate Q values (though it generally shouldn't completely explode). This can be addressed by using [Double DQN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06461) (note: this is an improvement that was added later on top of DQN).

Comment: With regards to the target network part, I have a second network (the 'online' network) that is used for choosing actions that go to the environment. Every 100 minibatches the online network's weights are changed to be those of the target network. Is that the wrong way to do it? I wasn't 100% sure from reading the paper whether the Q values of the next state were meant to come from the online or the target network (so I guessed the target network). I'll try with the 'next Q values' coming from the online network and see how that goes.

Comment: @Omegastick for a good reference implementation, see https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/DQN/dqn.py. One network (`q_estimator`) is used for selecting actions (line 273) and this one is also updated online (line 365). A different network (`target_estimator`) is used to compute targets (line 359), and only rarely updated (line 326)

Comment: The intuition you create in the first part does only hold for the first batch of training. If the training continues after the first update of the weights, the other notes will also have an error, redirecting them to their initial value. Of course training for small number of epochs won't yield 100% accuracy, so a small change their is possible and very likely. I think making this more explicit could improve this good answer further and prevent some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem in double DQN. Lowering the learning rate resolved it.